# steady_timer not firing

Tags: c++11, boost-asio

I need to be able to test that after an expiry time a function is called. After this failed to work I wrote a small MCE that demonstrates the essentials of the test. It returns without firing the handler.

Uncomment the line below 'is there a handler to expire?' causes it echo 1 to the console which means there is an unexpired handler.

According to the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_waitable_timer/async_wait.html) the

> The handler will be called when:
>
> - The timer has expired.
> - The timer was cancelled, in which case the handler is passed the error code boost::asio::error::operation_aborted.

So I think I should at least get 'handler' echoed to the screen when that line is uncommented.

Worryingly if you move it after the `sleep_for` and `yield` lines there is still a handler active.

Why isn't my timer firing?

MCE:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void handler(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    std::cout << "handler." << std::endl;
    if (!error)
    {
        std::cout << "Timer expired." << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    // Construct a timer without setting an expiry time.
    boost::asio::steady_timer timer(io_service);

    // expire immediately
    timer.expires_from_now(std::chrono::seconds(0));

    // Wait for the timer to expire.
    timer.async_wait(handler);  

    // is there a handler to expire?
    // std::cout << "Expiry : " << timer.expires_from_now(std::chrono::seconds(1)) << std::endl;

    // added to allow the timer to expire
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    std::this_thread::yield();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

You are using the asynchronous variant of `wait` without calling `io_service.run();`

> This call is required because operating system-specific functions have
>   to take over control. Remember that it is the I/O service in the I/O
>   service object which implements asynchronous operations based on
>   operating system-specific functions.

**Solution**

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    // Construct a timer without setting an expiry time.
    boost::asio::steady_timer timer(io_service);

    // expire immediately
    timer.expires_from_now(std::chrono::seconds(0));

    // Wait for the timer to expire.
    timer.async_wait(handler);

    io_service.run();
}
```

Comment: Okay. This works.  It would help if the example code on the boost site showed this. However having to start the `io_service` after the timer has begun is awkward to say the least.  Do I need to call `run()` every time I reset the timer? Will I need to `stop` or `reset` the service every time?  I have yet to create unit tests for this but the knowledge will help.

Comment: Have a look at this [tutorial](http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.asio-io-services-and-io-objects). I always reset then run the `io_service` after resetting the timer but I'm not sure if there is a way around that. If you can't have `io_service` run in your main thread then you can always run it in a background thread instead.